# hit power button at "tty1-6" the system shutdown immediately?

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when I hit the power button at **TTY1-6**, the system shutdowns immediately. I don't want the system shutdown, What can I do?

For more information:

a) I've try to modified `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` and it only works for TTY7(GUI).
 b) I modified the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file, `set HandlePowerKey=ingore;` and this did not work for me too.

Comment: I see an error here: `set HandlePowerKey=ingore;` it needs to be "ignore".

Comment: ;( you're right, I had a foolish mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your setting ...

```
set HandlePowerKey=ingore;
```

should be

```
set HandlePowerKey=ignore;
```

After I changed it in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and then rebooted tty1 through tty6 do no longer shutdown my machine. When I press the poweroff button it I get `^@` next to the login.

This is on a notebook and with 16.04.

**Please confirm if this is a typo in the question are actually what caused this**

---

The [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) has a couple of things to say about this:

```
HandlePowerKey=, 
HandleSuspendKey=, 
HandleHibernateKey=, 
HandleLidSwitch=, 
HandleLidSwitchDocked=
```

> Controls how logind shall handle the system power and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off or suspend. Can be one of "ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec", "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", and "lock". If "ignore", logind will never handle these keys. If "lock", all running sessions will be screen-locked; otherwise, the specified action will be taken in the respective event. Only input devices with the "power-switch" udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events. HandlePowerKey= defaults to "poweroff". HandleSuspendKey= and HandleLidSwitch= default to "suspend". HandleLidSwitchDocked= defaults to "ignore". HandleHibernateKey= defaults to "hibernate". If the system is inserted in a docking station, or if more than one display is connected, the action specified by HandleLidSwitchDocked= occurs; otherwise the HandleLidSwitch= action occurs.
>
> A different application may disable logind's handling of system power and sleep keys and the lid switch by taking a low-level inhibitor lock ("handle-power-key", "handle-suspend-key", "handle-hibernate-key", "handle-lid-switch"). This is most commonly used by graphical desktop environments to take over suspend and hibernation handling, and to use their own configuration mechanisms. If a low-level inhibitor lock is taken, logind will not take any action when that key or switch is triggered and the Handle*= settings are irrelevant.

- "HandlePowerKey= defaults to "poweroff"": So a wrongly set value would cause a poweroff.

Comment: Now I _really_ want to bind ^@ to some silly function... ;)